# Arreglo vacio PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en php, y me encontre con un problema al traer datos desde MySql. El error, o problema es que no trae ningún dato de la tabla "medicion".

Estoy usando WAMP, y el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_evasion");
if (!$enlace) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}   

$query = "SELECT * FROM medicion";

var_dump($query);
$resultado = $enlace->query($query);
var_dump($resultado);
echo "Retorno: ".count($resultado);

?>
```

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: Pese a que la tabla esta llena, no trae nada.

Comment: ok, podrias aclarar eso en tu pregunta?

Comment: debes poner un else despues del if

Comment: Ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás trabajando con mysqli como procedural y deberías de continuar con ese método si así lo prefieres en vez de tratarlo como objeto al llamar al método query del enlace.

```
<?php

$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_evasion");
if (!$enlace) {
  $mysqli_connect_error = "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL.".PHP_EOL;
  $mysqli_connect_error .= "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
  $mysqli_connect_error .= "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
  die($mysqli_connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM medicion";
$resultados = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultados) <= 0) {
  echo "No hay resultados de medición.";
} else {
  while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {
    // ...
  }
}

mysqli_close($enlace);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @dddenis por tu respuesta. Sobre esto mismo, tengo una pregunta.

Intentando pintar una tabla con los campos, no logro hacer que se pinten los campos use 

<tr>
   <?php 
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {
   ?>
     <td><?php echo $resultado->zPaga; ?></td>
   <?php
    }
   ?>
  </tr>

Pero no logro imprimir el o los campos.

Comment: Intenta acceder por índice. $resultado['zPaga']

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! No lograba dar con eso. Te pasaste